# when hosted a website shows system cannot find the file specified but work fine in debug mode

Tags: c#-3.0

When publish a site in local IIS it shows an exception system cannot find the file specified. But same code work fine in debug mode is there any solution for this.

Read the path from web config file.

Comment: It would be a good start to tell us what technology you use, is it ASP.NET MVC4?

Comment: @Robert Asp.net and not mvc4

Answer (score 0):

Check if the missing file is part of your project in the project explorer. If it is not part of your project, then it will not be published, but it nevertheless may work in debug mode, because the file(s) are locally available.

Comment: It is not a part of my project. But i want to check if that file exist in the server. if that file does not exist it will contact other server and get this xml file